# Regular expression not working inside string

Tags: regex, cucumber

I need to validate JSON through cucumber and this JSON is generated run time. JSON is like below.

```
{
"k1":["A", "B1234"]
}
```

Here 1234 is any random number appended with B.

I am using below template to validate any JSON like above-

```
{
"k1":["A", "B[0-9]+"]
}
```

But this is not working. I am getting message like Unable to validate JSON.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
{
"k1":["A", "B\[0\-9\]\+"]
}
```

it should work.